# How would I convert the timestamp that Trello uses into unix timestamp?

Tags: lua, timestamp, trello

So I'm trying to take the time that Trello uses in their card due dates and compare it with Unix time, as I find it easier to deal with when I have two Unix timestamps. However, I'm unsure as how to convert it.

Trello timestamps look like this:

```
2016-08-13T17:27:06.886Z
```

The first numbers are the date, and after the T is a time. The Z states that it's "Zulu time" which is the same as UTC.

So what I want to do is take that and convert it into a Unix timestamp using Lua.

Comment: This isn't a time stamp this is the JSON version of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out how to do it by looking closer at the os.time() function.

```
local function formatTime(s)
    local y = tonumber(string.sub(s, 1, 4))
    local m = tonumber(string.sub(s, 6, 7))
    local d = tonumber(string.sub(s, 9, 10))
    local h = tonumber(string.sub(s, 12, 13))
    local mi = tonumber(string.sub(s, 15, 16))
    local s = tonumber(string.sub(s, 18, 19))

    local tbl = {
        year = y,
        month = m,
        day = d,
        hour = h,
        minute = mi,
        second = s,
        isdst = (m>=3 and m<=10) --this is roughly close to DST, not perfect.
    }

    return os.time(tbl)
end
```

Using that, if I call the following:

```
formatTime("2016-08-13T17:27:06.886Z")
```

it would return a Unix timestamp corresponding to that time. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert time inside a web application or node js app,  you can easily use Moment.Js. 
http://momentjs.com

Comment: Moment looks like a great tool for web applications, however I'm trying to use Lua. Thanks anyway though.